Scrolling content when Flyout open
Simple page with two controls, Button and GridView. Button open a flyout with several another buttons. Gridview have a list of about 100 elements, so there is scrolling. If flyout of the button is opened, the scrolling will stop working, because the flyout is focused. How can I do if flyout is opened, the scrolling will continue working.
I use a UWP, C#.
Solved.
You can use popup instead of flyout, so the scrolling will be work correctly.

Could you please share the code snippet that could reproduce this behavior? Based on your description, it's an expected behavior because the flyout needs to be focused otherwise it will dismiss. This prevent the scrolling of other controls.

@RoyLi-MSFT I solve the problem by using a popup instead of flyout. If I use a popup, the scrolling work correctly

I found you solved the problem, please go ahead post your answer below and mark yourself, a good solution could help community member who view the solution later.

The solution is that using a popup control instead of a Flyout control. When using a popup, the scrolling still work as expected.
